# CSS/HTML random object not in code

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how to fix this and I know this question is kind of basic. A random object that is blocking my navigation bar is appearing on the browser side but not in the code, here:

[image http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/9861/s4oa.png](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/9861/s4oa.png)

But then in the code:
[image]

Please help me rectify this.

Comment: Might be worth checking if there's any JavaScript running on the page that's injecting the element?

Comment: checked doesn't look like it is.

Comment: What template engine is rendering the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue on your page is that the following element seems to be created automatically and it is altering the spacing for you:

```
<a original-title=""></a>
```

If you can use a style sheet you should be able to adjust just the home link as follows:

```
<a class="home-link" href="/index.php">...</a>
```

And add the following style rule:

```
a.home-link {
   margin-top: -18px;
}
```

This isn't particularly pretty or flexible so I would still strongly consider trying to determine where the element is injected and see if you can prevent it from happening. Good luck!

Comment: have you read the question???what u concluded is what OP has stated already....you are just re-quoting!!

Comment: @NoobEditor You are correct that I restated the question, but I don't believe the use of a style sheet (or inline style) was mentioned in the question as attempted solutions. Although these aren't great suggestions they will work to solve the exact issue as described.

Comment: well it works and although it isn't the best and it is a quick fix it works :P thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try moving the `clearfix` above `<ul>` tag as a separate div.

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<ul>
 <!--- all list -->

</ul>
```

**EDIT**

Though i doubt it would affect, but still, your `<a>` tag is not closed in below line :

```
<a heref="cashcapacity.com"><center><img src="{$theme['logo']}"/></center><a>
```

and

```
<div class="navigation_menu">

<div> <!-- either this div is uselessly mentioned or you forgot to close this div -->
```

Comment: edited:http://prntscr.com/2dpkbk 

still facing same problem

Comment: @user3133281 : can you post your html.....error must be somewhere in that only....showing images of code is not much of help!!

Comment: doesn't look like the comments box is very code friendly :P

http://pastebin.com/d6yik9qw

Comment: comment box is not for code....you can add it to your question...
i have added an edit....please correct the mentioned ones and check if it works!!